# Incorrect output for list of lists in python

Tags: python, list

```
def myLists(L):
    final_list=[] 
    sub_list=[]
    for each in L:       
        sub_list[:]=[]
        for num in range(each+1):            
            sub_list.append(num)
        #remove 0 from the list
        sub_list=sub_list[1:]    

        final_list.append(sub_list)        
    return final_list    

L=[1,2,4,5,7]
nl= myLists(L)
print nl
```

The expected output was :

```
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

I get the output as  follows, don't understand why "0" is added in the sublist:

```
[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

Comment: Are we supposed to guess at what the right output might be? Please do include a *minimum* explanation as to what you are trying to do, and what output you expect and what you got instead.

Comment: I guess you should give at least a few seconds before you start posting comments on a question ... is this some kind of a automated reply?

Comment: No, I am quite human, whatever people may tell you. Why not form a *complete* question first before posting?

Comment: The range-iterator, which you use to fill the sublists always starts with zero. So possibly you want to change its call to range(1, each+1)

Comment: You may also be interested in reading up on [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).  Assuming @guidot is right, then your entire code is simply `[range(1,each+1) for each in L]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you replace this:

```
#remove 0 from the list
sub_list=sub_list[1:]    

final_list.append(sub_list)
```

with this:

```
final_list.append(sub_list[1:])
```

you get your desired [output](http://ideone.com/XJxBzj).